# What is the physical meaning of non-commuting tetrads?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, reference-frames, differentiation, commutator

I'm [reading](https://www.physicsforums.com/attachments/grtetrad-pdf.45070/) about the tetrad formalism in GR and one main difference between the coordinate and the tetrad frame is that coordinate derivatives commute $\partial_\mu \partial_\nu = \partial_\nu \partial_\mu$, while tetrad derivatives do not $\partial_m \partial_n \neq \partial_n \partial_m$.

Considering that partial derivatives are variations along a direction and tetrads are simply an orthonormal frame, what is the physical interpretation of the non-commutativity of tetrad directional derivatives?

Comment: Well, the Lie bracket of vector fields $[X,Y](f)=X(Y(f))-Y(X(f))$ is in general non-zero. When the vector fields are just partials with respect to some coordinate system, then clearly they commute because partial derivatives commute. When your vector fields form an orthonormal basis, i.e., a vielbein, then they do not necessarily need to commute, and when they don't this just means they don't come from derivatives with respect to the coordinates of any chart.

Comment: Maybe you want the geometric interpretation of $[X,Y]$. If so, take a look at http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~simic/Spring11/Math213B/lie.bracket.pdf and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127792/geometric-interpretation-of-lie-bracket, and also Spivak's "A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry" Volume 1, where it is also discussed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by "tetrad derivative" you mean $\partial_m \phi \equiv e^\lambda_m \partial_\lambda \phi$, where $\partial_\lambda \phi$ is the partial derivative of a scalar field $\phi$ and $e^\lambda_m$ is the (inverse) tetrad.

Then the tetrad derivative is not a partial derivative. It is the partial derivative mapped to a locally inertial frame. Since this mapping generally depends on the manifold's coordinates, the commutator of tetrad derivatives will involve derivatives of the tetrad.

So for example,
\begin{equation}
\partial_m \partial_n \phi - \partial_n \partial_m \phi = \left[\partial_m e^\alpha_n - \partial_n e^\alpha_m \right] \partial _\alpha \phi
\end{equation}